# Is it possible to validate a textfield containing name as objectVO.fieldname using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way to validate a `textfield` whose name contains `objectVO . fieldName` using AngularJS?

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="submitForm($event)" novalidate() >
    <input type="text" name="OBJECTVO.FIELDNAME" ng-model="fieldName" required />
    <span class="error" ng-show="form.OBJECTVO.FIELDNAME.$invalid" >
</form>
```

I am using `Value Object` pattern and AngularJS understands only plain character fieldname of input fields.

How do I display error in ng-show?

*ng-show="form.OBJECTVO.FIELDNAME.$invalid"* is not valid statement. What is the correct way?

I have researched a lot, but I didn't find any useful content. Please help!

Comment: Angular Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

Comment: Take a look on this demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/81jgWv?p=preview

Comment: Input field contains `objectVO.fieldname`. How do I display errors in ng-show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the "array" notation for accessing the object's properties:

```
ng-show="form['OBJECT.FIELDNAME'].$invalid"
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/kuSDB/)**.

---

---

In JavaScript `obj.someProp` is shorthand for (and equivalent to) `obj['someProp']`.
This is usually useful for accessing an object's property when we don't know the name at "compile-time", but we know it at "run-time" (i.e. we know there will be a variable holding the name of the property we want to access):

```
function accessSomeProperty(object, propertyName) {
    return object[propertyName];
}
```

E.g.

```
propName = 'test';
accessSomeProperty(obj, propName);   // returns: obj[propName]
                                     //      === obj['test']
                                     //      === obj.test
                                     // with the benefit that 'test'
                                     // was specified dynamically
```